# Tile a set of images and pan/scroll across them using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a set of very large images that I would like to tile horizontally and pan across using ffmpeg.

The images are relatively large and can be created using magick using:

```
magick convert -compress lzw -size 90000x800 xc:"rgb(160,160,255)" test001.tif
... and so on
```

The command I've gotten closest with is the following:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i test%03d.tif -vf "tile=4x1,scroll=horizontal=0.05,crop=800:600:0:0,format=yuv420p" -t 10 output.mp4
```

The issues with the above command:

- it is very very slow (0.3 frames/sec)
- the animation loops because i picked an arbitrary 10 sec duration (not sure how to get it to stop at end of image)
- high memory usage, i'm not sure if ffmpeg is creating the tiled image first, and then going to process the video, or if there's a way to only access the areas of the tiffs that are needed for each frame

Any pointers for how scroll/pan across multiple input images would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: (1). the animation loops because `-loop 1` is set. (2) can you prep each frame image to 800x600 in magick? (3) Some operations seem very redundant to my eyes (tiling already huge image before cropping it very small).

Comment: @kesh ... I don't know if it's a bug, but if I do not tile before using `scroll` command the resulting video flickers between input images at x position as x pos increases. As for the looping, that's true, however I'm not sure how to relate the horizontal scroll speed (0.05 in my example) and setting the video duration.

Comment: Done a bit of experiment, `scroll` filter's 'horizontal' rate defines how much a frame gets rotated wrt its width from one frame to the next. So, if your input image is 4*90000x800 and rate is 0.05, one frame shifts image by 4*90000*0.05=18000 pixels, which is 20% of the original image width. `image2` demuxer (which is what you are using to read .tif) uses the default frame rate of 25 frames/second (you can change this by `-r` input option). So, in effect your current setup rotates its image out every 5 frames or 200 msec, which seems too fast to me...

Comment: So, here are questions for your intended effect: (1) how many images do you have? (2) how long do you want the video to last playing through all your images? (3) do you wish to pan from the left to the right of the same image, which is 90000 pixels wide? (4) is your final frame size 800 wide by 600 high, cropping out the bottom 200 pixels of the input?

Comment: 1) I have a few hundred images of this size :| 2) video can and will be very long, i'm assuming it will be close to a day long #dontaskquestions 3) i want to pan *all* images from left to right as if they were seamlessly tiled horizontally 4) the crop is wrong in my original question, it will be 1280x800

Comment: (2) ok, let me change the question. How quickly do you want the video to consume one image? This will set your frame rate (3) >all images from left to right< This is what I was afraid to hear. What I think you need to do requires `tile` , `fps` , and `crop` filters. Let me concoct my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with 90000x800 images (hundreds of them), use input framerate of 1 fps (for the ease of presentation), let `M = 90000`

step 1: `tile=2x1:overlap=1` appends the next image to the previous: [Img1|Img2],[Img2|Img3], [Img3|Img4]...

step 2: `fps=N` increases the frame rate to `N` fps by repeating each tiled frame `N` times

step 3: `crop=w=1280:h=800:x=mod(n,N)*M/N:y=0` positions the current video frame on the image then crops out the rest. On frame n=N, the next pair of images will be set so it resets the frame position to 0.

```sh
ffmpeg -r 1 -i test%03d.tif \ 
  -vf 'tile=2x1:overlap=1, \
       fps=N, \
       crop=w=1280:h=800:x=mod(n,N)*M/N:y=0' \
  -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

Pick your number for `N` and substitute the symbols with actual numbers, and you should be ready to roll (I hope...)

But now, how do you pick `N`? It'll depends on your *input* frame rate (which is preliminary set to 1), your desired *output* frame rate, and the image transition time...

Say you want each image to stay on screen for 2 seconds and the output frame rate to be 30 fps, then each image should appear on 2*30=60 frames. So, set N = 60 and the input frame rate 30/60 = 0.5.

I have not tested the command, so give it a try and I'd be happy to troubleshoot if not working. Also, I'm curious if it's reasonably fast.

===============================

Update: requested to change input to 800x800 images instead of 90000x800.

Change `tile` and `crop` as follows:

```sh
ffmpeg -r 1 -i test%03d.tif \ 
  -vf 'tile=3x1:overlap=2, \
       fps=N, \
       crop=w=1280:h=800:x=mod(n,N)*800/N:y=0' \
  -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

Also `N` needs to be readjusted by `Nnew = 800/90000 * N` or thereabouts.

Comment: Wonderful explanation! It works great btw, not even a tweak needed. Was speedy too... was processing a solid 120 FPS! (Tiff's have random access ability and if ffmpeg uses libtiff then the crops might also be very speedy)

Comment: Good to hear! I used `geq` filter with a long expression in the past, and it slowed down to a snail speed so I wasn't confident `mod(n,N)*M/N` won't cause a similar slowdown.

Comment: Hey kesh, I had to adjust my input images to be square.. so instead of fewer 90000x800, there are way way more 800x800's. It seems if i try to `crop=w=<larger than 800>` (because i want output to be 16:9) it screws things up. Do you know how I could accomplish this? If not no worries, you've already been super helpful

Comment: Hold on, I'm not following what you are changing. are you just inputting bunch of 800x800 images and still try to get 1280x800 video out of it?

Comment: If that's true, then the key is in the `tile` filter. What you want to do is that the tiled image has more than 1280+800=2160 pixels wide. With 800x800 in, you need to tile 3 of them at a time for the right-most frame to have all its columns defined. In other words, you need to tile 3 images: 800x3=2400>2160. See `tile=3x1:overlap=2` would do the trick for you.

Comment: I tried `tile=3x1:overlap=1` without incrementing the overlap. what you said worked like a charm. many thanks!

Comment: Oh that's right, you are correct `overlap=1` it is. Each tile covers its first two images. Glad you caught it.

Comment: Nope, take back what I just said. `overlap` must be `2`. I've updated my answer with how to change the rest of the filtergraph